# Create Xunit Test Methods dynamicaly based on Excel data

Tags: c#, selenium, xunit, ui-testing

Testing team will create test cases in XLS (100+ cases)

[image]

I have to create the `Test Methods` for the each cases dynamically at run time.

I can write the logical part to validate whether the test case is pass or fail, but the only thing I want is how to create the test methods at run time. I am using the Xunit Test project in C#.

Suggest a solution to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do some kind of **row-testing**:

Each line would be a different test run.

```
[Theory,
InlineData("1", "Description 1", ...),
InlineData("2", "Description 2", ...),
InlineData("3", "Description 3", ...)]
public void Can_get_correct_age_for_date(string sno, string description, ...)
{
    // you can access the paramaters here
    Console.WriteLine(sno);
    Console.WriteLine(description);

    // Assert Logic
    Assert.Equal(...);
}
```

In your scenario i think you need to rearrange your Excel file or write yourself some kind of "custom excel parser".

Do you get the idea?

Comment: Yeah, It's interesting. But is there any way to change the Test Method name (Can_get_correct_age_for_date) for each InlineData?

Comment: Name It as you like.